# DateTime returns wrong value in https and correct value in http

Tags: php, datetime, https

I have a simple file to return the current server time,This is my code

```
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>
```

When I open the file via **http** its showing the right time but when I open it with **https** the time is off from a few seconds to a almost 30 min.

At first I thought this was a cache problem but even after I disable the cache this is persisting.

**Edit**

The time is called with this script which is in the main php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function serverTime() { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({url: 'https://url/timeset.php', 
        async: false, dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }}); 
    return time; 
}

</script>
```

If the script calls the datetime its returning the **datetime when the php file was last opened in a browser**. So if some one opens the page the script is in then the datetime the above code returns is wrong and when that page is refreshed the datetime returned does not change still returning the incorrect i.e old date time.

Is there any way I can keep refreshing the php every second or so? 
Since its only a small file with only the datetime it shoudnt use much resources...

Comment: I've just tested this above code on my server.  It returns the same time for both HTTP and HTTPS.  The only thing I think this is, is the caching.  Are you *certain* all caching is indeed off?

Comment: What happens if you use `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); echo date("M j, Y H:i:s O);` ?

Comment: Is this app deployed to multiple servers in a web farm?  If so, perhaps you are just hitting a different server that has it's clock set wrong.

Comment: @JohnCrawford Yes I am pretty sure that caching us off. When I open the webpage in browser and incorrect time is shown once I refresh it correct time is shown. Is there any way I can make sure that caching is off?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I tries the code but its the same problem.

Comment: @MattJohnson Johnson Nope, this is a single server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update I see that you are using `AJAX` for retrieving this data so here are a few debugging techniques:

- **Always** physically visit the URL in question and see if it acting the same
- In `$.ajax` you should set `cache: false`
- In `$.ajax` you can manually append your URL with a GET parameter to always fetch fresh like this `url: 'https://url/timeset.php?fresh='+randomNumberFunction()`
- In PHP set a few headers at the top of your script : `header("Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"); header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");`
- Get acquainted with the Network Tab in your web browsers Debugging tools

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working, Rather than having a script fetsh the date from a php file I just used the javascript date functions to return the date in the format and time zone I needed.

Thanks for the suggestions